# Is this a flaw in Groovy's implementation of Singleton pattern?

Tags: groovy, singleton

A straight forward implementation of a Singleton pattern without using Metaclass:

```
class A{
    static final instance = new A()
    private A(){}

    static getInstance(){return instance}
}
```

Why is it that the private constructor is not respected by groovy? Though one can tell by intuition that it is a singleton looking at the pattern, Unlike java, such an implementation does not restrict the programmer from creating a new instance of this class using `new A()` outside the scope of this class. So shouldn't this be considered as a flaw in its implementation?

Comment: Have you tried using the [Singleton annotation transform](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-create-singleton-class.html?m=1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the code above with:

```
@Singleton
class A{
}
```

and access the singleton instance via:

```
A singleton = A.instance
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in current Groovy implementation, so nothing is really private in Groovy. Take a look at its [JIRA issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-1875). I also wrote [a short article](http://semberal.eu/blog/exploring-private-field-access-in-groovybeans) about it recently.